# Greasemonkey (userscript) prevent link click ajax post

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey, userscripts

I am trying to prevent an AJAX post when a user clicks on a link.

So far, I have this, but preventDefault() is not working:

```
$('.link-class').live('click', function (event) { 
    console.log("live----Stopped?!?!"); 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    return false; 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Too many things could be going on, link to the target page.

In general, if intercepting `click` doesn't work, try intercepting `mousedown` and `mouseup` as well, as some pages trigger off of those, instead.

```js
$('.link-class').live ('click mousedown mouseup', function (event) { 
    console.log ("live----Stopped?!?!"); 
    event.preventDefault (); 
    return false; 
 } );
```

Comment: yup tried "click mousedown mouseup" but no luck. ajax post is still happening.

Comment: Like I said, too many things could be happening to list.  Link to the target page and/or provide a fully self-contained example of the problem. Beware that if the site is a Google app, they are notorious for FUBAR'd javascript that is very hard to userscript.

Comment: You are definitely correct. The JS is very cryptic. I was just hoping that I can prevent post requests regardless of what or how they are doing it. as far as the direct target page, well I am trying to write a user script that will make you confirm that you really want to like something on FB. :)